# Complete Rust plugin install for VS Code via command line

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'd like for my students to program Rust from within VS Code under Windows 10. I hope to provide the IT department with a set of scriptable commands to set this up on each machine.

I have installed Rustup. I also execute the following to install the "Rust (rls)" plugin:

```
code --install-extension rust-lang.rust
```

When I then open VS Code, I receive a popup message at the bottom right:

```
RLS not installed. Install?
```

If I select "Yes" everything goes well. What I would prefer, is for this step to have been completed earlier via the command line (as above with `--install-extension`). Is this possible? Am I missing another extension? Can this be installed via the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RLS is not a VSCode extension. You can install it via `rustup` (I'd say before installing VSCode extension): `rustup component add rls rust-analysis rust-src`

More on RLS [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls)